# How to use image.xcassets in XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5.1

I am trying to use the image.xcassets in the newer xcode versions but i need to understand it better before proceeding it. Can any one help me out of it like,
1. what is image.xcassets exactly? 
2. what is the purpose of using it?
3. how do i add and delete images into the assets?
4. is this only for launcher and splash images or is it possible to use our app images too?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read about [Asset catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH1-SW1)  from apple doc

Answer (score 1):

It is a utility in xcode that provide ease to add `launch images` and `app-icons`.

Just make the icon size and launch image size accordingly and drag them to the respective place.

I think for app icon **58*58**,**80*80** and **120*120** are the sizes, and for lauch image **640*960** and **640*1136** just make your .png images to those sizes add them to your project and place over there.

To remove image from there right click on that and remove item.